# Silex 2: Get route in before middleware

Tags: php, routes, silex

I have defined a ***before*** middleware in my Silex 2.0 application, and I would like to know what route is being processed.

For instance:

If I am loading the URL `/hello/foo`, I want obtain the string `/hello/foo` in some variable from my before middleware.

If I am loading the URL `/en/hello/foo`, I want obtain the string `/en/hello/foo` in some variable from my before middleware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$request->getPathInfo()` should work

Comment: Thanks!, other useful method is: $request->getRequestUri()